# Footer floats on page and not at bottom

Tags: css, html

I am building a page and for some reason my footer will not stay at the bottom of the page, it basically floats right in the middle of "article".

I add postion absolute, and bottom 0 but does not work

You can view a live example here: http://codepen.io/bskousen/full/rqbHc

Comment: Try position fixed instead of absolute

Comment: Fixed doesn't work because I want it to stay at the bottom and not be see when its out of view, I appreciate the suggestion, I added position relative and that worked.

Comment: Seems to be at the bottom for me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding this in the css:

```
footer
{
 position:static;
 clear:both;
}
```